# How do I see which condition returned false if i have multiple conditions within one if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
if (condition_1 and condition_2 and condition_3 or condition_4):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: The same way you would see anything else. Trace / debug.

Comment: Eee, divide them into multiple `if...elif` statements? Put `print`s? I don't really get the question.

Comment: @freakish the only reason i didn't want to divide them up was because the code gets a lot more messy with if statements all over the place.

Comment: @JonKolman Dude, that's the price you pay for knowledge. ;)

Comment: Given the current code, what does it matter? They all make up one condition that determines what you want to return.

Comment: Do you want to check for debugging reasons or do you actually need the information later on?

Answer (score 0):

```
x=None
y=None
z="yesitis"
result=["first true" if x and y else "second true" if z else False]
```

If x and y are present it will return "first true" or if z is present it will return "second true".
Or if you want you can return also True

```
[True,"one"] if x and y else [True,"second"] if y else False
```

Answer (score 0):

Because all those entities are bundled up tou really have no way of knowing which part is returning false, so there are two ways:

1) Separate all the conditions into separate if/else statements. This is easy to do, and only requires you to repeat the if/else and only including one condition at a time. (EASY)

2) Whatever condition you are trying to acheive, such as a specific answer to a question or a hexed key, try to "turn it off and on" in a sense and purposely try to put a false command through that if statment to see which one is not working. This is complex and may take a while, and can only work for a select condition that you can control, but if you are looking to keep a minimal line of code, this works. (HARD)